# Method for adding commas to digit string in Java

Tags: java, string, digits

The assignment is to add comes after every three digits looking from right to left. So number 1000000 should be 1,000,000 etc.

I have relatively good idea how to tackle this problem, but I have no idea why am I getting no output. Maybe I am making some mistake that I am not aware of or something...

I think that I understand concept that Strings are immutable, so they cannot be changed in place and when you want to change something to string you have to make new string object. But I dont get how is this possible then:

```
`result = ch + result;`
```

and this

`result = "," + result;`

What am I getting wrong here ?

```
   import acm.program.*;
   import acm.util.*;

    public class AddCommasToNumericString extends ConsoleProgram{

        public void run(){
            while(true){
                String digits = readLine("Enter a numeric string: ");
                if (digits.length() == 0) break;
                println(addCommasToNumericString(digits));
            }
        }

        public String addCommasToNumericString(String digits){
            String result = "";
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = digits.length()-1; i <= 0 ; i--){
                char ch = digits.charAt(i);
                result = ch + result;
                counter++;
                if (counter % 3 == 0){
                    result = "," + result;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(digits)` will do the job.

Comment: @bhantol Yes of course, but I suspect his assignment is to do this manually to learn how to work with strings.

Comment: Yup thats why I asked so that I don;t post this easy solution.

Comment: In case you haven't already found the answer to why you can do `result = "," + result` when strings are immutable, it's because all variables are _references_ to objects and are not objects themselves. So when you say `result = something...` you are only setting the variable `result` to refer to a new string; you are not actually changing the string itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest eliminating the `counter` and use only the loop variable by making a small change:

```
public String addCommasToNumericString(String digits) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=1; i <= digits.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = digits.charAt(digits.length() - i);
        if (i % 3 == 1 && i > 1) {
            result = "," + result;
        }
        result = ch + result;
    }

    return result;
}

addCommasToNumericString("123");     // 123
addCommasToNumericString("12345");   // 12,345
addCommasToNumericString("1234567"); // 1,234,567
```

Comment: Every time is like this, I complete some assignment and always make these goddamn typing mistakes! I Tnx Tim.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the read line into an `Integer`, then format it as a `String`

```
String digits = readLine("Enter a numeric string: ");
Integer myInt = new Integer(digits);
String output = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(myInt.value());
```